# I tried asking a sub-question to get answers, and got marked duplicate

Tags: discussion

I recently asked this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017757/1593077

Which did not get any answers except "Don't know". So, I decided to limit my scope and ask about something more specific:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/23523702/1593077

Now, the original question is still relevant in itself, it's just, I guess you could say 'harder'. Should I have really acted differently? What would be better practice in such a situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2nd question reads a bit as:

> My previous question wasn't answered, so let's ask it again.

Now someone with domain knowledge will probably be able to tell the difference, or perhaps notice that the one's a subquestion of the other (and vote to close), but people with less than the ideal amount of domain knowledge do wander by and may cast their vote.

Your options are:

- Clearly and explicitly addressing how the questions are different in the second question - either in the question body, or the comments.

  People tend to be a bit quicker to close things as duplicates of earlier questions by the same users if they look similar - it's best to address these issues prior to someone else bringing it up.
- Not posting a second question, but rather just editing the first, or simply deleting the first.
- As the other answer mentions, posting a bounty on the first question (without posting a second) might also work.

---

Note - your first question sounds a bit like "asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" (i.e. off topic), but I could be wrong (I'm not entirely sure what falls under that reason and what doesn't any more).

Answer (score 2):

One could maybe say with **all/most/many** in the title of the first question you also include the **explicit enum based** you ask for in the second question.

Why not editing the first question so that the error codes you are most interested are also mentioned and then put a bounty on it?

Also both question could still be deleted since they have no upvoted answer. You could therefore also start new. With the possible direction: Error codes for CUDA frontend warnings, especially for explicit enum based types. Or whatever.